# Await is only allowed within async functions error react native

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I am new to react native and trying to save user obejct in application storage using `await AsyncStorage.setItem('user', res[1].data);`  
However I am getting error as
[image]

```
handleLogin = async() => {
        NetInfo.fetch().then(state => {
            if (state.isConnected) {

        const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
        const data = {
            email: this.state.userName,
            password: this.state.password
        };

        fetch(`${DOMAIN_URL}/login`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        })
            .then((response) => {
                const statusCode = response.status.toString();
                const data = response.json();
                return Promise.all([statusCode, data]);
            })
            .then((res) => {

                if (res[0] == 200) {
                    await AsyncStorage.setItem('user', res[1].data);
                    navigate('Home');
                }else{
                    Alert.alert(
                        res[1].message
                    );
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });

            }
            else {
                Alert.alert(
                    "No Internet!",
                    "Needs to connect to the internet in order to work. Please connect tablet to wifi and try again.",
                    [
                        {
                            text: "OK",
                            onPress: () => { }
                        }
                    ]
                );
            };
        })
    };
```

I have made the `handleLogin` async but it doesn't solve the error. What is the correct way to store user obejct?

Comment: `await` is inside the callback function of `.then()` that arrow function is not async

Comment: I made a new async function called and navigateToHome and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended that you use [react-native-easy-app](https://github.com/chende008/react-native-easy-app/blob/master/README.en-US.md) , through which you can access any data in AsyncStorage synchronously.

[Sample_Hooks](https://github.com/chende008/Sample_Hook)

[StorageController](https://github.com/chende008/Sample_Hook/blob/master/src/Main/Home/view/StorageController.js)

Answer (score 0):

```
   navigateToHome = async (user) => {
        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('user', user);
        navigate('Home');
    }

    handleLogin = async() => {
        NetInfo.fetch().then(state => {
            if (state.isConnected) {

      
        const data = {
            email: this.state.userName,
            password: this.state.password
        };

        fetch(`${DOMAIN_URL}/login`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        })
            .then((response) => {
                const statusCode = response.status.toString();
                const data = response.json();
                return Promise.all([statusCode, data]);
            })
            .then((res) => {

                if (res[0] == 200) {
                    navigateToHome(res[1].data);
                }else{
                    Alert.alert(
                        res[1].message
                    );
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });

            }
            else {
                Alert.alert(
                    "No Internet!",
                    "Needs to connect to the internet in order to work. Please connect tablet to wifi and try again.",
                    [
                        {
                            text: "OK",
                            onPress: () => { }
                        }
                    ]
                );
            };
        })
    };
```